# Why is this question closed as duplicate?

Tags: discussion, exact-duplicates

I asked a [question about water purification](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/q/29/46) and it got closed as an [exact duplicate](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/q/7/46),  but I don't agree.

I really don't so how both question are duplicates. [My question](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/q/29/46) is about the difference between purification methods (very broad), while [the other question](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/q/7/46) is about the safest way (rather specific).

Am I missing something here? If not please vote to reopen.

Answer (score 7):

Regardless of those semantic differences, **this would be so much better as a canonical answer.** A complete answer would review the various methods **and** discuss the pros and cons of each— including which is the "safest" method.

Providing this information in one awesome, authoritative answer is the type of content that will provide fantastic inroads for searchers into this site. Why split up the discussion on semantics?

Answer (score 4):

I'm in agreement with you here. I would say that the other question about the safest method is likely to also be answered in a question regarding the different methods - that is, an answer to that is likely to (or should) include how safe each method is. But, should the other question be closed as a duplicate is another matter.