# Lots of similar small questions vs one comprehensive canonical answer?

Tags: discussion, exact-duplicates

Related to this question on meta [Why is this question closed as duplicate?](https://outdoors.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27/why-is-this-question-closed-as-duplicate) what are the lines for duplication where the question isn't exactly the same, but the reference duplicate contains the answer as well as more comprehensive information? I'm referring specifically to the question of knots.

We have individual knot questions:
[How do I tie a Prusik knot?](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/338/how-do-i-tie-a-prusik-knot)
[How do I tie a double fisherman's knot?](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/430/how-do-i-tie-a-double-fishermans-knot)
 [How do I tie a bowline knot?](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/432/how-do-i-tie-a-bowline-knot)

Versus a more comprehensive knot answer, 
[What are good knots to know for camping and backpacking?](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/73/what-are-good-knots-to-know-for-camping-and-backpacking)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can imagine people finding both options useful - people looking for detailed information for a specific use and people looking for a more general guide. If both formats prove useful (people up-vote them), then both should stay.

The obvious drawback is potentially maintaining duplicate information, but I think linking answers is an acceptable solution.

Answer (score 7):

The "what are good knots" question is too broad. It mixes up "which knots should I know" with "how do I tie those knots" and "what are the pitfalls" (like tying a square knot as a bend).

Still, I wonder if we should really have a knot tying SE!

Answer (score 2):

For the outdoors, there are a lot of questions which need supporting information, not just a quick answer:

- Climbing-Belaying
- Climbing-anchoring
- Rescue related questions
- Kayak or raft scouting
- Emergency medicine or support
- Search and rescue

What about taking the "large" answers and turning them into a community wiki? These are important topics, should the editing be restricted?

Answer (score 0):

I lean towards having canonical answers with more information regarding closely related topics and / or pros and cons of different things as opposed to each question being isolated from the rest.